# jquery class manipulation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, addclass

Im getting an "unexpected ;" error at line 4 and I don't see it.

```
$('.socialtag').hover(function(){
var tab = $(this);
if(!tab.hasClass('extended')){
    $(tab.addClass('extended');
    $(tab).animate({
            left: '1115px'
    }, 1500)
}
else{
    $(tab).animate({
            left: '975px'
        },1500);
    $(tab.removeClass('extended')
    };
};
```

I've been staring at it for an hour now, and I really don't see it.
It is supposed to take an image with the class .socialtag and check if it has the class extended. If not then it should change the css left property to 1115px in 1.5 seconds and add the extended class. If so then it changes the property to 975 (which the image already has by default so there would be no visual change).

Can anyone see my error?

Comment: http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: AGILE MATTER `;)` check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
tab.addClass('extended');
........................
tab.removeClass('extended');
```

As you are already initializing element object to variable so no need to use `$` before `$(...)`

**Or**

You can do like this:

```
$(tab).addClass('extended');
$(tab).removeClass('extended');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I chose to go with option 1. works perfectly. I'm a hack scripter and thought I would need the jquery $ to use a jquery function.

Whoops.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(tab.addClass('extended');
```

missing parenthesis at least

```
$(tab.addClass('extended'));
```

Answer (score 0):

$(tab.addClass('extended'); missing parenthesis,

Try this: $(tab).addClass('extended');